# liferay template: how to encode url

Tags: liferay, velocity

For some reason when I'm using liferay in internet explorer it does not seem to accept cookies.
So I guess I need to encode my URLs.

I tried `httpUtil.encodeURL('http://x.com/y',true)` but that just gets me http://x.com/y again without the JSessionID appended.

Answer (score 0):

VelocityTools has a LinkTool that can encode urls too.  Also, make sure that a session has been created.

Answer (score 0):

The EscapeTool is an alternative to the LinkTool